# django list all objects with user specific info for loop error

Tags: django, loops

I am using Django to build a site mainly to learn something about websie building.And I came across something I thought is strange.I have this code below:

```
all_words=Word.objects.all()[0:100]
    user=request.user
    wordlist = []
    //wordinfo = {} --->This doesn't work
    for word in all_words:
        wordinfo = {}//This works fine
        taged_word = FlagWord.objects.filter(word = word,user = user)
        if taged_word :
            wordinfo['usertag'] = True
        else:
            wordinfo['usertag'] = False
        wordinfo['word'] = word
        wordlist.append(wordinfo)
```

Notice where the `wordinfo` is placed.I think both would work because the latter content would  replace the previous one anyway.But when it's placed outside the `for` loop,I would get 100 elements in the `wordlist` which are all the same.The `word` property would all be the last `word` in `all_words`.

I know if the `wordinfo` is placed in the `for` loop,a new `wordinfo` would be created.But question is I think if it's placed outside the `for` loop,it should also work.Can somebody explain to me what's the difference?Why can't it be placed outside the `for` loop?

Comment: what is not working when you place `wordinfo = {}` outside of the `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in python variables reference objects.  so when wordinfo is outside of the loop the values it contains are referenced by your list of values.

This means that on your last itearation all the values in wordlist will be equal to the last value assigned to `wordinfo`

so at the end of the loop you will have

```
wordlist = [wordinfo, wordinfo, wordinfo, wordinfo] # 100 times
```

if wordinfo is eaual to `{'usertag': True, 'word': 'because'}` all the items in the list will have that value.

you could further refactor this to look something like:

```
  all_words=Word.objects.all()[0:100]
  user=request.user
  wordlist = []
  for word in all_words:
    taged_word = FlagWord.objects.filter(word = word,user = user)
    usertag = False
    if taged_word :
        usertag = True
    wordlist.append({'word': word, 'usertag': usertag)
```

Comment: This means that on your last itearation all the values in wordlist will be equal to the last value assigned to wordinfo...I thought every loop the value of wordinfo would be different...Does this have something to do with lazy evaluation or something?

Comment: @Gnijuohz, lazy evaluation has to do with the django querysets.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy

Comment: One thing I don't quite understand is that if I retrieve a object from  the database using filter method,I found that I know for sure there would be only one object,but I have to use for loop to iterate it in my template or it went wrong.Why is that?(I am sorry it seems to be another question :P)